# Run .exe using python. Wait for it to complete and then close the command prompt of that exe

Tags: python

How can I run a .exe from python, wait for that .exe to complete execution and then close the command prompt that was opened when the .exe started executing. So basically in the end I am trying to close the .exe file that was opened earlier but only after it has completed its execution.

```py
os.system('C:/mybackup/imageautomation/Etl.PrepareAttachments.exe')                       
'''I want the above exe to run and after completion close itself and 
then run the exe in the below command'''
os.system('C:/mybackup/imageautomation/Etl.UploadAttachments.exe')
```

Comment: subprocess https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: os.system('C:/mybackup/imageautomation/Etl.PrepareAttachments.exe') this runs the exe but does not close it once done. I have to manually close the command prompt in which the exe is running.

Comment: If you know about `os.system` so, why don't you try `os.system('exit')`

Comment: @vaku I want to run another exe after the completion of first exe.

Comment: so when do you want to exit...

Comment: @vaku after executing the second exe file

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard given you have not supplied your efforts but I think this is what you're trying to do;

```
import sys

sys.exit()
```

Comment: I have updated what I am trying to do in the code above.